# Authentication between Next.js frontend and NestJS backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, jwt

### Question

I need to add authentication to a Node.js app but I know nothing about authentication.

My requirements are:

- I need to be able to verify the authentication in the backend, and find the associated user in my PostgreSQL database
- I want this solution to be secure enough to pass a pentest / SOC 2 compliance
- I need to be able to add auth providers such as Google & Salesforce
- I want it to be easy. I don't want to implement myself complicated stuff related to sharing token between tabs, etc.
- Ideally, I would like all my API routes to be only in the NestJS application and not in Next.js to keep only one node server and simplify my deployments

### Context

My project is a Nx monorepo with the following structure (NestJS for backend, Next.js for frontend):

```
├── apps
│   ├── backend      # NestJS backend
│   └── frontend     # Next.js frontend
├── dist
│   ├── apps
│   └── libs
├── node_modules
├── README.md
├── nx.json
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.base.json
├── workspace.json
└── yarn.lock
```

### Personal research

I found Passport.js for the backend and NextAuth.js for the frontend. They seem to handle most of the hard work for me. I found a way to make them work together: get a JWT token in the frontend from Google, send this token to my server, which verifies the token and send a new token, send the new token to the frontend and use it for authenticating the following requests (https://arunoda.me/blog/add-auth-support-to-a-next-js-app-with-a-custom-backend).

However if I use NextAuth.js, it forces you to define API routes in Next.js, so I will end up with two node server which will be more tricky to deploy.

Comment: Have you found a good way to do this ?